# Add And statement to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this function:

```
public  List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
{
}

Find(x => x.Id == 4);
```

Inside the method `Find` I want to chain `And` Condition.
something like:

```
query.And(x => x.Secured == false);//Secured is a memeber inside T like Id.
```

Comment: Its where not and you can have multiple of them.`Statement.Where(query).Where(x => !x.Secured);`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want to access a member of `T` within the generic method. `T` could be anything at this point so the compiler will not let you access `Secured` since `T` may not have a `Secured` member.

You could cast `T` to `dynamic`, but this just changes a compile time error to a runtime error (plus it's horrible).

The best way would be to ensure `T` implements some known interface that has a Secured member.

```
public  List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) where T : ISecured
```

Comment: Or use expression trees as xanatos suggests :) Again this moves the problem to runtime though.

Answer (score 0):

The expression must be "opened" and rebuilt, like this:

```
public List<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = query.Parameters[0];
    Expression body = query.Body;

    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Secured");

    body = Expression.AndAlso(body, Expression.Not(property));

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> query2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

    // Now you can use query2

    return null;
}
```

Note that I'm considering this `x.Secured == false` to be equivalent to `!x.Secured`. Clearly `Secured` could be a strange class that overloads the `==` operator, but I'll ignore that case.

As suggested by @Ralf, you could even simply do two `.Where`. like:

```
public List<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = query.Parameters[0];

    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Secured");

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> query2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(property), parameter);

    return context.Set<T>
        .Where(query)
        .Where(query2)
        .ToList();
}
```

(I'm using as an example `context.Set<T>`, that is very similar to what you would do if you are using Entity Framework, but in general nearly all the `IQuerable<>`/`IEnumerable<>` treat two `.Where()` like a single `.Where()` with an `&&` condition)

Answer (score -4):

Something like

```
Find(x => x.Id == 4 && x.Secured == false);
```